# Register generic Autofac factory

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dependency-injection, autofac

I have ICommand and `ICommandHandler<TCommand>` interfaces and I want to inject to factory. Could you please check and let me know what i do wrong? I do it as below:

CommandBus - here i received error (shown below in blackquote)

```
var handler = _context.Resolve<ICommandHandler<TCommand>>();
```

I Register my command handler in AutofacModule class

```
builder.RegisterType<CreateMakeCommandHandler>()
    .As<ICommandHandler<CreateBaseCommand<MakeEntity>>>();
```

> Autofac.Core.Registration.ComponentNotRegisteredException: The requested service 'Shop.Services.CommandHandlers.BaseCommandHandlers.ICommandHandler'1[[Shop.Domain.Commands.Model.CreateModelCommand' has not been registered. To avoid this exception, either register a component to provide the service, check for service registration using IsRegistered(), or use the ResolveOptional() method to resolve an optional dependency.
>      at Shop.Services.CommandHandlers.BaseCommandHandlers.CommandBus.d__7'1.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\Shop\Shop\Shop\Services\CommandHandlers\BaseCommandHandlers\CommandBus.cs:line 31

Thank you in advance.

Edit:

```
public class CreateBaseCommand<TEntity> : BaseCommand where TEntity : BaseEntity
{}
```

Comment: Have you looked into Autofac's built-in `RegisterGeneric()` method?  Does that meet your needs?

Comment: Your `Resolve` doesn't match your `RegisterType`. You've got a nested generic in the latter.

Comment: I edited my previous post and i put CreateBaseCommand class. I think Resolve match my RegisterType. If you think this is not correct can you please give me some tips how to correct RegisterType?

Comment: You're trying to resolve `ICommandHandler<T>` but you're registering `ICommandHandler<T1<T2>>`. Also, the error says that you're trying to resolve `CreateModelCommand` which you haven't included in your question